# How to specify filepath in java?

Tags: java, debian, debian-based

I have created a java application for "Debian Linux." Now I want that that application reads a file placed in the directory where the jar file of that application is specified. So what to specify at the argument of the File Object?

```
File fileToBeReaded = new File(...);
```

What to specify as argument for the above statement to specify relative filepath representing the path where the jar file of the application has been placed?

Comment: The title should perhaps be "How to find where my program is installed in Java?"

Comment: exactly, that's what I intended. Thx for the downvote

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know the name of the file, of course it's simply

```
new File("./myFileName")
```

If you don't know the name, you can use the File object's list() method to get a list of files in the current directory, and then pick the one you want.

Answer (score 9):

Are you asking about escape character issues?

If that is the case then use forward slashes instead of backward slashes like

> "C:/Users/You/Desktop/test.txt"

instead of

> "C:\Users\You\Desktop\test.txt"

Answer (score 5):

Using relative paths in `java.io.File` is fully dependent on the current working directory. This differs with the way you execute the JAR. If you're for example in `/foo` and you execute the JAR by `java -jar /bar/jar/Bar.jar` then the working directory is still `/foo`. But if you `cd` to `/bar/jar` and execute `java -jar Bar.jar` then the working directory is `/bar/jar`.

If you want the root path where the JAR is located, one of the ways would be:

```
File root = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("").toURI());
```

This returns the root path of the JAR file (i.o.w. the classpath root). If you place your resource relative to the classpath root, you can access it as follows:

```
File resource = new File(root, "filename.ext");
```

Alternatively you can also just use:

```
File resource = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("filename.ext").toURI());
```

Comment: Can you please suggest with the .war rather than the jar. I am finding difficulty to get the file path of an image file when the app is deployed on a jboss server. I have raised separately a question for this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54161215/how-to-refer-to-a-file-present-within-src-main-resources-folder-deployed-in-a-jb/54161697?noredirect=1#comment95158413_54161697

Comment: Hey @Shirgill :) Depending on server type, WAR deployment usually loads individual files into memory not into disk. Therefore `java.io.File` referencing a WAR-packaged file won't always work. Before giving an answer, you'd better first tell what exactly you need this `File` for and why `InputStream` is not sufficient. E.g. perhaps you need this for some 3rd party API which stubbornly only accepts `File` and not `InputStream`, such as iText PDF.

Comment: Yes, while constructing the PDF file, I need to create an image object  `Image logo = Image.getInstance(path)` exposed by iText PDF. I see that there is an overloaded method which takes in an `Inputstream` object. But other requirement is related to loading a font file(Arabic) `BaseFont baseNormalFont = BaseFont.createFont(PATH, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);`  I need to give the path of the same file. For the time being, I have put the file under a separate configuration folder in linux , and then gave the path as `System.getProperty(".....path to the conf folder") + further path to font file`.

Comment: The above approach works well but is the same not achievable if the file is part of the maven project. Please suggest. Btw, how did you arrive specifically at iText. I see that I haven't mentioned it anywhere ::))

Comment: @Shirgill: because this was asked before :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/32251711 Your answer is also there and most likely option 4 is the best for you.

Comment: That is stunningly informative. Thanks for your generosity.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do the trick:

```
File starting = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File fileToBeRead = new File(starting,"my_file.txt");
```

This way, the file will be searched in the `user.dir` property, which will be your app's working directory.

Answer (score 2):

You could ask your classloader to give you the location of the jar:

```
getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

...but I'd suggest to put the file you are looking for inside your jar file and read it as a resource (`getClass().getResourceAsStream( "myFile.txt" )`).

Comment: The resource does not have to be in the JAR file - you can add directories to the classpath as well.

Answer (score 1):

On IntelliJIDEA right click on the file then copy the absolute path, then in the double quotation paste the path as filePath.
for example it should be something like this:

```
"C:\\Users\\NameOfTheComputerUser\\IdeaProjects\\NameOfTheProject\\YourSubFolders\\name-of-the-file.example"
```

Comment: This ended up being what I needed in C# Sikuli4Net