# Load Font from /WEB-INF/resources/fonts/foobar.ttf with iTextPdf FontFactory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, fonts, itext, itextpdf

The question pretty much says it all. I get following exception:

```
ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: /fonts/CALIBRI.TTF not found as file or resource.
Caused By: java.io.IOException: /fonts/CALIBRI.TTF not found as file or resource.
    at com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory.createByReadingToMemory(RandomAccessSourceFactory.java:263)
    at com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory.createBestSource(RandomAccessSourceFactory.java:173)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:148)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.process(TrueTypeFont.java:641)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:375)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.getAllFontNames(BaseFont.java:1229)
    at com.itextpdf.text.FontFactoryImp.register(FontFactoryImp.java:446)
    at com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory.register(FontFactory.java:341)
    at bean.createPdf.makePdf(createPdf.java:358)
    at bean.auswahl.buttonProbenbegleitschein(auswahl.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.broadcast(UIXComponentBase.java:1113)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:179)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.event.ProxyEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(ProxyEvent.java:72)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.broadcast(UIXRegion.java:124)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:111)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171)
    at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:115)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1074)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:402)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:192)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at de.lkvsh.rdv.portal.authlib.servlet.PortalFilter.doFilter(PortalFilter.java:116)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Physical location of font file is `/WEB-INF/resources/fonts/CALIBRI.TTF`
So as far as I see it, it can't be not found in resources by iTextPDf `FontFactory`.

Comment: META-INF or WEB-INF? What is your code?

Comment: Please add the Weblogic version, and the small part from code createPdf.java near line 358

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.6/com/itextpdf/text/io/RandomAccessSourceFactory.java#RandomAccessSourceFactory.createBestSource%28java.lang.String%29) of iText's `RandomAccessSourceFactory#createBestSource()`, the [`FontFactory#register()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/FontFactory.html#register(java.lang.String)) can only take a path representing a valid (relative) disk file system path, or a resource URL (e.g. HTTP URL or classpath URL), not a WAR resource path. You actually supplied a WAR resource path which you can usually pass to `ServletContext#getResource()`, `getResourceAsStream()`, `getRealPath()` and `getRequestDispatcher()` only.

There are several ways to get it to work:

1. Convert the WAR resource path to an absolute disk file system path with help of [`ServletContext#getRealPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath-java.lang.String-):

   ```
   String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/resources/fonts/foobar.ttf");
   FontFactory.register(path);
   ```

   The caveat is that this method is highly unportable and environment-dependent. Among others, this will fail when the server is configured to expand the WAR straight into memory instead of on local disk file system, or uses a virtual file system. E.g., by default, it may work on Tomcat, but it may not work on WebLogic. Your stack trace confirms that you're using WebLogic. The chance is big that the `getRealPath()` will by default always return `null`.

   ---
2. Move the font file outside `/WEB-INF` folder so that it's publicly accessible by a HTTP URL. Provided that you can move whole `/resources` folder one level up, outside `/WEB-INF`, and that the font is accessible by `http://localhost:8080/context/resources/fonts/foobar.ttf` (first test in a normal webbrowser to be sure), then just supply exactly that path.

   ```
   String path = "http://localhost:8080/context/resources/fonts/foobar.ttf";
   FontFactory.register(path);
   ```

   You can if necessary dynamically construct `http://localhost:8080/context` (the base URL) as below:

   ```
   String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
   String baseURL = url.substring(0, url.length() - request.getRequestURI().length()) + request.getContextPath();
   String path = baseURL + "/resources/fonts/foobar.ttf";
   FontFactory.register(path);
   ```

   The caveat is that, by default, anyone in the world could download it, even when only guessing the URL.

   ---
3. Move the font file to the classpath. I.e. make sure it ultimately ends up in `/WEB-INF/classes` among all those Java class files and class resource files (such as properties files). Let's assume that the package name is just `fonts`. In case you're using Maven, just put it in `/main/resources/fonts/foobar.ttf`. In case you're using a "plain vanilla" web project with only a `src` folder where you put all your Java packages and class source files, then create a package `fonts` the usual way and put the `foobar.ttf` file right there. Then you can supply a path of `/fonts/foobar.ttf`.

   ```
   String path = "/fonts/foobar.ttf";
   FontFactory.register(path);
   ```

   This is clearly the preferred way.

   ---
4. In case none of above options apply, your last resort is creating a temporary file with help of [`File#createTempFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-) in container managed temporary folder, grabbing the WAR resource contents by [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-), writing it to the temp file and finally provide the absolute temp file path.

   ```
   String tempDir = (String) getServletContext().getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR);
   File tempFile = File.createTempFile("foobar-", ".ttf", new File(tempDir));
   InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/resources/fonts/foobar.ttf");
   Files.copy(input, tempFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
   String path = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
   FontFactory.register(path);
   ```

   ---

<sub>Note: the above answer assumes that the code is placed in a "plain" Java EE servlet class. In case you're using JSF — as confirmed by the stack trace — you can obtain the `ServletContext` by [`ExternalContext#getContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getContext--), the `HttpServletRequest` by [`ExternalContext#getRequest()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequest--), the `ServletContext` attributes by [`ExternalContext#getApplicationMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getApplicationMap--), the real path by [`ExternalContext#getRealPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRealPath-java.lang.String-), and the resource stream by [`ExternalContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the great and very complete answer!

Comment: Wow, I did not think anyone would answer this :D But it has been an issue ever since. I will try it out tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

`java.io.IOException: /fonts/CALIBRI.TTF not found as file or resource.`

I think iText library is looking for fonts directly under WEB-INF folder instead of /WEB-INF/resources.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. In the future, better post educated guesses as a comment first instead of as an answer.