# getting error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, jsch

this is the error i got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0  at TrfFiles2Dev.main(TrfFiles2Dev.java:55
```

this is the code I'm working on

```
public  void send (String fileName) {
    String SFTPHOST = "";
    int SFTPPORT = 22;
    String SFTPUSER = "";
    String SFTPPASS = "";
    String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "";
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TrfFiles2Dev.class.getName() );
    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    System.out.println("preparing the host information for sftp.");
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
        session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Host connected.");
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        System.out.println("sftp channel opened and connected.");
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
        File f = new File(fileName);
        channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
        log.info("File transfered successfully to host.");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println("Exception found while tranfer the response.");
    }
    finally{

        channelSftp.exit();
        System.out.println("sftp Channel exited.");
        channel.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Channel disconnected.");
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Host Session disconnected.");
    }
}   
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TrfFiles2Dev trfFiles2Dev = new TrfFiles2Dev();
    trfFiles2Dev.send(args[0]);
}   }
```

Thank you in advance for any help. I'm not looking to have this done for me, I'm just stuck and need help finding my way.

and how to make this possible to transfer file from my server to other server?

Comment: What is line 55 in TrfFiles2Dev

Comment: Which line you are getting error?

Comment: Can you share this class with the numbered lines?

Comment: Basically this error is telling that the array you are accessing at line 55 does not have the index within the array size that you are trying to use.

Comment: likely 55 is trfFiles2Dev.send(args[0]);, which means you did not specify any command line arguments when running the program

Comment: line 55 is trfFiles2Dev.send(args[0]); can you tell me how its can be work?

Comment: java TrfFiles2Dev     myFileName.txt

Comment: and how i can send all my file in directory ? thanks in advanced

Comment: does the file have to be in one directory with this java file to send, cause i get the exception found while transfer the response?

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems). Your question can be answered very quickly and easily with your step-debugger. You should always try and solve your problems with a step debugger before coming to StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

You need to supply the `program arguments` for it to run.

If you are using some ide like `eclipse`.

```
Goto run-> run configurations-> give arguments-> then run
```

Incase you are using from `cmd` use something like:

```
java TrfFiles2Dev you-file-name-here.txt
```

You can also take the `fileName` while program is running using `Scanner` class. Something like:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileName = scn.nextLine();
TrfFiles2Dev trfFiles2Dev = new TrfFiles2Dev();
trfFiles2Dev.send(args[0]);
```

Comment: does the file have to be in one directory with this java file to send, cause i get the exception found while transfer the response?

Comment: i used terminal and how i can send all my file in specific directory ? thanks in advanced

Comment: File has to be on classpath. But if you are unsure of that, you can use absolute path of file like `C:\\results\\you-file-name.txt`

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693020/how-to-specify-filepath-in-java to get more details how to give the file path.

Comment: But primary reason for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is lack of program arguements in your case.

Comment: I'm not sure what remains unclear from my code snippets. Make sure you read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem