# How to refer to a file present within src/main/resources folder deployed in a jboss env?

Tags: java, jboss-eap-6

I need to look up for an image present in `src/main/resources` folder in a web application. Its an `Apache CXF SAOP` based web application.

We are running it in a `jboss env(jboss-eap-6.4)`

After building the war, the same is deployed.

However, I am unable to get the correct path to the above file.
Please suggest.

I have tried multiple options.

```
File logo= new File("src/main/resources/image.jpg");    
logo.getAbsolutePath(); //  This works great when Junit tested, however breaks with the server.
```

Neither does this works-

```
ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
contextClassLoader.getResource("image.jpg").getPath();
```

Comment: The first one works with JUnit because you lauch the JVM running JUnit with a working directory that is the root of your project, from which the relative path `src/...` does point to the correct file. Once deployed there won't be such a file outside your war, so you need to make the second option work. Make sure the `src/main/resources/` directory is present in your war and specified as a classpath root.

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: @rustyx : Yes, we are using Maven

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using Maven, files from `src/main/resources` will end up on the classpath automatically.

To load a resource from the classpath, use something like this:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image.jpg");
```

Getting the path to the resource or opening it as a `File` may not always work though since the file is probably still stored inside a `.war` file. `class.getResource()` will therefore return a `URL` that is recognizable only by the app server's classloader.

Comment: I need to get the resource path and not the input stream as shown above. When I deploy the application in my local on JBoss, I get the path as `/D:/Servers/RedHat-JBoss/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/appName-1.0.war/WEB-INF/classes/image.jpg`. When I try to read the file it fails, saying FileNotfoundException. Please suggest.

Comment: Well you can't. That path doesn't actually exist. There is only `D:/Servers/RedHat-JBoss/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/appName-1.0.war`, the rest `/WEB-INF/classes/image.jpg` is inside the .war.

Comment: You mean to say that if there is an image file within src/main/resources folder and the app is build/deployed to the jboss server, it is not possible to get the path of that image file.

Comment: The Maven build process compiles and packages all the source files into `appName-1.0.war`, like a ZIP. That single file is deployed to jboss.

Comment: But all the properties and xml files which are inside the same war, they work fine and are loaded perfectly. If I can't get the path of the file as in my case suggested by you, how come the application works fine with properties and other files. Any suggestions.

Comment: It's possible you could get a path if you use an exploded deployment, but I wouldn't really suggest it. What is the reason you need the actual path for?

Answer (score 0):

This is my file structure within the Maven project:

```
src/main/resources/
src/main/resources/META-INF
src/main/resources/adir
src/main/resources/adir/afile.json
```

Finally,this worked for me:

```
String resourceName = "adir/afile.json";
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL resource = classLoader.getResource(resourceName);
InputStream iStream = resource.openStream();
byte[] contents = iStream.readAllBytes();
System.out.println(new String(contents));
```

HTH,
Thomas